# How to get a user authenticated token in sitefinity

Tags: php, web-services, curl, sitefinity

I want to call the sitefinity web service: users.svc/authenticate. I am running a local instance of my sitefinity web site, and I am also running a local php website (using wamp). When I call this web service through the php file, I get a 401 (unauthorized) error. I think there are one of two problems.

1.My syntax is wrong. This is some of it for analysis purposes:

```
$serviceString =
"http://localhost:60876/Sitefinity/Services/Security/Users.svc/authenticate/";
$provider = array(
"MembershipProvider" => "",
"Password" => "password",
"Persistent" => true,
"UserName" => "admin"
);
$fp = fopen("test.txt", 'w');
$curl = curl_init($serviceString);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $provider);
if(!$curl_response = curl_exec($curl))
{
trigger_error(curl_error($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);
fclose($fp);
```

2. I am going about this process wrong. I have come to the conclusion that I may need to create some kind of custom web service within my sitefinity project, that will create a token, and pass it out to the php site. I'm hoping that this isn't the case, because it seems harder, but if it is, at least I know where to start over. Also, if anyone knows anything about this, please tell me where I can start.

Answer (score 1):

Check us out from @timw255 Everything you need to authenticate with php

https://github.com/timw255/SitefinitySTS-PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right you cannot access the service from there.  I think you have to create the services in a Public folder in order for you to access them without already being authenticated.

In other words instead of:

"http://localhost:60876/Sitefinity/Services/Security/Users.svc/authenticate/"

you need to create (move) your service here:

http://localhost:60876/Sitefinity/Public/Services/Security/Users.svc/authenticate/